# How can update usercontrol in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page and an user control on it.

I have a two buttons in the user control for create or remove session, and a label that shows a session text, when click the buttons nothing happens and user control doesn't update I should refresh the page,

Would you please anybody help me to fix this issue ?

This is my master page markup:

```
<form runat="server">
   <div>
       <!--previous codes-->
       <nav class="navigation">
           <div class="wrapper"> 
               <controller:menu runat="server" ID="menu" />
               <controller:user runat="server" ID="user" />
           </div>
       </nav> 
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"> 
       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       <!--Next Codes-->
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my user control

```
<ul class="nav signup">
    <li class="no-drop-down">
        <asp:Label ID="_signupbutton" runat="server" CssClass="sr">Test</asp:Label>
            <div class="signup-dropdown">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="_defaultuser" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <div class="notloggeduser">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="usercontroller" 
                         OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Text="????">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
           </asp:PlaceHolder>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="_signedup" runat="server" Visible="false">
               <div class="defaultuser">
                   <ul>
                       <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="_userlogout" runat="server"  CssClass="usercontroller" OnClick="_userlogout_Click">
                                <i class="fa"></i>????
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this is user control codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         if (Session["signup"] == null)
         {
              _signupbutton.Text = "??? ??? / ????";
              _defaultuser.Visible = true;
         }
         else
         {
             _signupbutton.Text = "<i class=\"fa\"></i> " + Session["signup"].ToString();
             _signedup.Visible = true;
         }
    }
}

protected void _userlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Remove("signup");
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Add("signup", "????? ??????????");
}
```

Comment: "when click the buttons nothing happens and usercontrol doesn't update I should refresh the page, " Can you explain this more?

Comment: @shubham I mean after clicking text of label doesn't change and I should refresh the page manually from browser.

Comment: add setting your placeholders visibility (i.e. `.Visible="false"; //or true`) in your `button_click` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of events is a bit messed up here.

`Page_Load` will execute before the event handlers for the click events. You need to perform the setup of the button state from the event handlers, as if you do it in page load your session object wont have been updated yet.

You will need to do a few things here (this isn't tested but should show you the logic):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) // This will run when the page is loaded but not from a post back / button click etc (e.g. from your page refresh)
    {
      this.SetButtonState();
    }
    else
    {
      // use this for things you want to happen on postback only
    }
}

private void SetButtonState()
{
   if (Session["signup"] == null)
   {
      _signupbutton.Text = "??? ??? / ????";
      _defaultuser.Visible = true;
   }
   else
   {
      _signupbutton.Text = "<i class=\"fa\"></i> " + Session["signup"].ToString();
      _signedup.Visible = true;
   }
}

protected void _userlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Remove("signup");

    // Update your button state
    this.SetButtonState();
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Add("signup", "????? ??????????");

    // Update your button state
    this.SetButtonState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It was great but now masterpage and webform don't get updated, just user control content updates.